# How can merge header column in python?

Tags: python, numpy, csv, data-science

I have read  a url "https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states" using read_html with pandas library:

[image]

But I have issue in header cell merging like below image mark

[image]

And I want to merging row or column of header to them to achieve above format and same format to save in csv file.

Means same format https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states to store in CSV file using to_csv

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, the starting df is a list. To make it into a dataframe you can use:

```
df=df.concat(df)
type(df) # Returns pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(df.columns) # Returns pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex
```

Your header is a multi-index object. Here is some reference https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html. 
When we print the columns we get this:

```
print(df.columns)
```

output:

```
MultiIndex([(                        'Name',                         'Name'),
        (      'postal abbreviation[1]',       'postal abbreviation[1]'),
        (                      'Cities',                      'Capital'),
        (                      'Cities',                   'Largest[5]'),
        (  'Established[upper-alpha 1]',   'Established[upper-alpha 1]'),
        ('Population[upper-alpha 2][3]', 'Population[upper-alpha 2][3]'),
        (               'Total area[4]',                          'mi2'),
        (               'Total area[4]',                          'km2'),
        (                'Land area[4]',                          'mi2'),
        (                'Land area[4]',                          'km2'),
        (               'Water area[4]',                          'mi2'),
        (               'Water area[4]',                          'km2'),
        (              'Numberof Reps.',               'Numberof Reps.')],
       )
```

And our columns has two levels:

```
print(df.levels)
```

Output:

```
[['Cities', 'Established[upper-alpha 1]', 'Land area[4]', 'Name', 'Numberof Reps.', 'Population[upper-alpha 2][3]', 'Total area[4]', 'Water area[4]', 'postal abbreviation[1]'], ['Capital', 'Established[upper-alpha 1]', 'Largest[5]', 'Name', 'Numberof Reps.', 'Population[upper-alpha 2][3]', 'km2', 'mi2', 'postal abbreviation[1]']]
```

You can replace your column header with :

```
Index=[('Name', ''),('postal abbreviation[1]',''),('Cities',                    'Capital'),('Cities','Largest[5]'), ('Established[upper-alpha 1]',''),('Population[upper-alpha 2][3]', ''),('Total area[4]','mi2'),('Total area[4]', 'km2'),('Land area[4]','mi2'),('Land area[4]','km2'),('Water area[4]','mi2'),('Water area[4]','km2'),('Numberof Reps.',' ')]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(Index)#To make it into a MultiIndex item
df.columns=index
```

So now if you run the command

```
print(df)
```

You will have the result you want!

[image]